# simple html dom parser or a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

There is a html page, it contains a block:

```
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td class="tcat" colspan="2">
Some regular text <span class="normal">the desired text 1</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="alt1" colspan="2">
<span class="smallfont"><a href="page.php?u=00001">link1</a>, <a href="page.php?u=00002"><i><b><font color="#006400">link2</font></b></i></a></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Help me to parse with simple html dom library or a regular expression, so that would be deduced only here it is:

```
the desired text 1 <span class="smallfont"><a href="page.php?u=00001">link1</a>, <a href="page.php?u=00002"><i><b><font color="#006400">link2</font></b></i></a></span>
```

If I do this:

```
<? 
include 'simple_html_dom.php'; 
$html = file_get_html('http://some-url.com/power.html'); 
foreach($html->find('td[class="tcat"]') as $element1)  
       echo $element1. '<br>';  
foreach($html->find('span[class="smallfont"]') as $element2)  
       echo $element2. '<br>';     
?>
```

So, along with the necessary data also are displayed more similar elements that presents on the page. (with the same parameters 'td class="tcat"' and 'class="smallfont"')
I need that would be deduced only that:

```
the desired text 1 <span class="smallfont"><a href="page.php?u=00001">link1</a>, <a href="page.php?u=00002"><i><b><font color="#006400">link2</font></b></i></a></span>
```

Comment: "Help me" suggests that you've tried something. Have you?

Comment: Madara Uchiha Look up and read what is under it: "If I do this:"

Comment: What do you need to extract from the html exactly?

Answer (score 2):

It's all about [knowing css](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/):

```
echo $html->find('td.tcat span', 0)->text();  
echo $html->find('span.smallfont', 0);
//the desired text 1 <span class="smallfont"><a href="page.php?u=00001">link1</a>, <a href="page.php?u=00002"><i><b><font color="#006400">link2</font></b></i></a></span>
```